# Why is UTF8 saved as 16 bit encoding from two Mac OSX programs?

Tags: macos, utf-8

I'm having a fairly large problem with text encoding, and in the process of trying to solve it I saved a text file consisting of entirely non-exotic characters, from TextEdit and TextWrangler on Mac OS X, choosing UTF8, only to find that each character occupied 16 bits when I viewed the files in a hex editor.  This seems wrong to me.  What am I missing?  Are these bugs I should be reporting?

Answer (score 0):

My mistake.  The text editors are being very clever and I am underestimating them.